# Django: Storing templates in DB: Define API (variables in context)

Tags: python, django, templates

I want to store django templates in the database and make them editable for via web.

Next, I want to define template types: A template type defines the allowed variables of the context.

Examples:

- Invoice-Template-Type gets these variables: customer_name, invoice_id, ...
- Voucher-Template-Type gets these variables: voucher_id, voucher_amount, ...

The people how edit the templates (stored in db, edit via web) should see the available variables and get a warning if they use variables which are unknown.

How to get this done or am I reinventing the wheel?

Comment: I can give you the  structure of models as  how to connect each of them with Foreign keys and different variables,but you need to implement view and logic by yourself if that's what you want??

Comment: What have you done so far? Is there already models? Also why store them in db? You can store them as files and use `FileField` in your `Template` model. I think this is possible to do, but not sure if there is already implementation.

Comment: Also know that you asked about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40082181/install-django-applications-via-admin-interface. Are trying to build CMS? I think looking into this may also help https://www.django-cms.org/en/

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev What I have done so far? I have coded nothing for this. I like to think and talk in the beginning. I want to avoid to run into the wrong direction. Yes, I could use a FileField, too. I will update the question. I am not building a CMS. I want to improve an existing application.

Comment: PrakharTrivedi my current main goal is to avoid reinventing the wheel. If nothing exists that matches, then I want how to structure this.

Comment: After looking more into django-cms looks like they have implemented this.
https://www.django-cms.org/en/blog/2016/02/16/build-a-website-without-knowing-python-django-part-three/ and https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/release/3.4.x/cms/models/static_placeholder.py. Not same but close

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev thank you this information. DjangoCMS seems in good shape. I would need to put my current application into it. I have to think about this, since I guess this is a lot of work. Is there no simpler solution ...